# I want to know how to rewrite the url in linux server through .htaccess

Tags: php

We are using “front/” in the URL that is visible to the public: http://www.iict.com/front/property/property_detail.php?pid=12?  I want to remove all details from the URLs that don’t need to be there (e.g.“front/property”).  This should be: http://www.iict.com/property_detail.php?pid-12.

Please help me on this issue. I am using Linux-based server

Answer (score 1):

for http://www.iict.com/property_detail/12

make a file called anything.htaccess.txt then place the lines below in it

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^property_detail/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ front/property/property_detail.php?pid=$1
```

upload to your hosting, then rename the file too ".htaccess"

Comment: RewriteRule ^property_detail?pid-([0-9]+)$ front/property/property_detail.php?pid=$1

Answer (score 0):

You're better off doing this at the web server level - for instance, if you're using Apache, use mod_rewrite.

You could then make the URLs even cleaner, for instance: http://www.iict.com/property/12.

If you specify which server software you're using, someone could probably provide an example, or at least point you to the appropriate docs.

EDIT: Apache's mod_rewrite docs are at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html - if you're using Apache, that will be a useful read.

Comment: What?  I've asked you a question, which you haven't answered, and pointed you at documentation which will tell you what to do if you're using Apache.  I'm not your employee standing by to provide a ready-to-use solution, you have to be willing to help yourself.

Comment: sorrry this types of mistakes never again please .

Answer (score 0):

This is not rewrite in php.
This is rewrite in your web server, what web server your have?

Comment: Yes defenately please give some idea about it .I am using Apache server